# Space around Inline blocks

Tags: html, css

Please consider this Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WooLwL

There are 3 divs in one container div and the sum of all divs width is 960. However upon inspection, there is this white space around the divs that I cannot get rid of via CSS. I've confirmed the margin is 0.

```
<div id="columncontainer">
  <div id="column1">
    yolo
  </div>
  <div id="column2">
    <hr>
    all column 2 data here
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div id="column3">
    all column 3 data here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: This question has been asked a lot of times. Please do some research before posting a question on SO. Check this [**Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add float:left

```
div#columncontainer div {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyyvxp)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
div{
  float:left;
}
```

which will solve inline-block problems

```css
body{
  background-color: #ccc; // page background color
}
div{
  float:left;
}
#columncontainer {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#column1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  background: #b3e;
}

#column2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  background: #555;
  
} 

#column3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #999;
}

#footer {
clear: both;
}

#image {
margin-left: auto;
}

#columncontainer {
background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Inline Block Nerd Zone</h1>

<div id="columncontainer">
<div id="column1">
yolo
</div>

<div id="column2">
<hr>
all column 2 data here
<hr>
</div>

<div id="column3">
all column 3 data here
</div>
</div>
```